# Matrix equal to linear transformation $T:A \rightarrow A^t$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following problem.

Let $T : Mat_{2×2}(\Bbb R) \rightarrow Mat_{2×2}(\Bbb R)$ be the linear map given by $T(A) = A^t$. Is it possible to represent T as a matrix?

Thoughts: It seems to me that if I treat an element of $Mat_{2×2}$ as an element in $\Bbb R^4$ then it is easy, but not as something that will right-multiply a $2x2$ matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Any* linear map between finite-dimensional vector spaces can be represented by a matrix. (So the boring answer to the question is "yes".)

To find it, just pick any basis of $\text{Mat}_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$ as you would for any other vector space. The matrix you are looking for would be a $4 \times 4$ matrix (as the dimension of $\text{Mat}_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$ is $4$).

(Can you convince yourself that there is no $2 \times 2$ matrix $B$ such that $AB = A^t$ for any $A$?)